# Formatting for Firehose transformation output

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am using AWS Kinesis Firehose with a custom Data Transformation.  The Lambda's written in Python 3.6 and returns strings that look like the following:

```
{
    "records": [
        {
            "recordId": "...",
            "result": "Ok",
            "data": "..."
        },
        {
            "recordId": "...",
            "result": "Ok",
            "data": "..."
        },
        {
            "recordId": "...",
            "result": "Ok",
            "data": "..."
        }
    ]
}
```

This Lambda is perfectly happy, and logs outputs that look like the above just before returning them to Firehose.  However, the Firehose's S3 Logs then show an error:

`Invalid output structure: Please check your function and make sure the processed records contain valid result status of Dropped, Ok, or ProcessingFailed.`

Looking at the examples for this spread across the web in JS and Java, it's not clear to me what I need to be doing differently; I'm quite confused.

Answer (score 13):

If your data is a json object, you can try following

```
import base64
import json
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    output = []
    for record in event['records']:
        # your own business logic.
        json_object = {...} 
        output_record = {
            'recordId': record['recordId'],
            'result': 'Ok',
            'data': base64.b64encode(json.dumps(json_object).encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
        }
        output.append(output_record)
    return {'records': output}
```

base64.b64encode function only works with b'xxx' string while 'data' attribute of output_record needs a normal 'xxx' string.

Answer (score 5):

I've found the same error using Node.js.

Reading the documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/data-transformation.html my mistake was not base64-encoding of the data field of every record.

I resolved doing this:

```
{
    recordId: record.recordId,
    result: 'Ok',
    data: new Buffer(JSON.stringify(data)).toString('base64')
}
```

Comment: I am also facing this issue. Tried what you suggested, still not able to resolve. Same message keeps coming.